# TFS Build artifacts error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, tfs

I'm working on an application in Visual Studio 2015. I use Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2015 to build my project.

After the successful build (the app runs on all staging environments) I copy the build Artifacts and upload them to our production environment.

However, when I try to upload the .edmx, I get the following error message:

**Error!
Error while doing import : Bad JSON escape sequence: \s. Path 'Data.Login', line 1, position 160.**

Do you know what could be the issue?

thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your build/release definitions?

Comment: Are you using  [Publish Build Artifacts](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/utility/publish-build-artifacts) to upload  your build Artifacts? Could you share more detail related log? You could also [Enable Verbose Debug Mode](https://www.benday.com/2016/09/19/enable-verbose-debug-mode-for-tfs-build-vnext/) for trouble shooting.